# Gershgorin theorem with complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, gershgorin-sets

I'm having problems with the Gershgorin circle theorem with complex numbers...

Let $T:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a linear transformation $T(x, y, z, w) = (x+2z, 2αy+2z−w,12x + 3y − 5z, x + y − iz + 12iw)$ $α\in \mathbb{K}$

There's a bunch of options, but the correct one is "If $|α| > 10$ then T is diagonalizable."

I found all the circles:

$C_1=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-1|\le 2\}$

$C_2=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-2α|\le 3\}$

$C_3=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z+5|\le 7/2\}$

$C_4=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-12i|\le 2-i\}$

But I don't know how to find out if they're disjoint. (I'm kind of dumb with complex numbers lol)

EDIT: My problem is just with $C_3$... I don't know what to do with a complex radius

EDIT: This is how I found all the circles:

$E$ being the standard basis, the associated matrix for T is:

$_{E}(T)_{E}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 2  & 0 \\
    0 & 2 \alpha & 2  & -1 \\
   1/2 & 3 & -5 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & -i & 12i \end{bmatrix} $

So $C_1$'s center is $1$ and radius $0+2+0=2$, $(1, 2)$

$C_2$'s center is $2\alpha$ and radius $0+2+1=3$, $(2\alpha, 3)$

$C_3$'s center is $-5$ and radius $1/2+3+0=7/2$, $(-5, 7/2)$

$C_4$'s center is $12i$ and radius $1+1-i=2-i$, $(12i, 2-i)$

Comment: Complex numbers are not ordered, so $|a|\leq 4-i$ simply makes no sense. Looks like a typo. Also for the case of $C_4$, no complex number would have negative moduli.

Comment: Yep, somehow all the circles were wrong, but I still get a complex number as a radius on $C_4$...

Comment: Could you show your work to find these circles? Showing work is also considered good practice on this site, and maybe someone could pinpoint a minor mistake somewhere in your development.

Comment: Just edited my post showing how I found the circles

Comment: To compute $R_i$ as defined on the wikipedia link, you should have taken the modulus at each entry. Hence $C_4$ radius is 3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Comment: Oh, that really does make sense, I didn't find that in my linear algebra text book. Thank you!!